# Developing for mobile devices with .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, barcode-scanner, vb6-migration

We're beginning the conversion of our VB6 WMS application to .NET, and part of that development will be handheld scanners(e.g. RF and bar codes) specifically the `MC9090`.

Did Microsoft quit supporting the Compact Framework after Visual Studio 2008?

What options are available for developing on this device?

Comment: Your options are pretty much to use the .NET 3.5 CF.  Your options are limited because it runs an unsupported operating system at this point.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft, as of right now (mid April 2013 for future readers), supports CF 3.5 under Studio 2008.

[Newer versions of Windows Embedded Handheld](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/2013/jan13/01-14Handheld.aspx) (WEH), which is what most handheld scanners, etc will likely be migrating to, will be supported under Studio 2012, but will be based on Windows Phone, so the programming paradigm shifts greatly.

For vanilla Windows Embedded Compact (WEC, which used to be called "Windows CE") which will be used in embedded devices, [Visual Studio 2012 and CF 3.9 will be supported in WEC 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/11/16/introducing-netcf-3-9-in-windows-embedded-compact-2013-a-faster-leaner-and-multi-core-runtime.aspx), due out this quarter (ending June 30, 2013).

So, for a device available today, CF 3.5 and Studio 2008 is the choice.  Making sure the UI and the business logic are very well divorced would be wise, as you're likely going to be porting the code to Silverlight under Studio 2012 for the next generation of devices.